# How to open or access a webpart's XML and rename its namespace Using PowerShell?

Tags: web-part, powershell

We have some web parts deployed in our Sites, which are not working due to Migration from MOSS to SPS2010, and I need to replace the namespace used by power shell by accessing the Webpart's XML..

Comment: If the answer solved the problem statet in your question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$xml = [xml](get-content file.xml)
$xml  = $xml.OuterXml.Replace("xmlns=`"whatever`"", "xmlns=`"new`"")
```